# I failed to retrieve comments using PHPWord

Tags: comments

I failed to retrieve comments using PHPWord. I have tried multiple formats of Word documents, but I couldn't retrieve the comments successfully. The comments appear empty, and I'm not sure what the reason is.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBvvz.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDRvs.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCHqi.png) I've tried many ways, but none of them worked